# How do I force one field in Ruby's CSV output to be wrapped with double-quotes?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm generating some CSV output using Ruby's built-in CSV. Everything works fine, but the customer wants the name field in the output to have wrapping double-quotes so the output looks like the input file. For instance, the input looks something like this:

```
1,1.1.1.1,"Firstname Lastname",more,fields
2,2.2.2.2,"Firstname Lastname, Jr.",more,fields
```

CSV's output, which is correct, looks like:

```
1,1.1.1.1,Firstname Lastname,more,fields
2,2.2.2.2,"Firstname Lastname, Jr.",more,fields
```

I know CSV is doing the right thing by not double-quoting the third field just because it has embedded blanks, and wrapping the field with double-quotes when it has the embedded comma. What I'd like to do, to help the customer feel warm and fuzzy, is tell CSV to always double-quote the third field.

I tried wrapping the field in double-quotes in my `to_a` method, which creates a `"Firstname Lastname"` field being passed to CSV, but CSV laughed at my puny-human attempt and output `"""Firstname Lastname"""`. That is the correct thing to do because it's escaping the double-quotes, so that didn't work.

Then I tried setting CSV's `:force_quotes => true` in the `open` method, which output double-quotes wrapping all fields as expected, but the customer didn't like that, which I expected also. So, that didn't work either.

I've looked through the Table and Row docs and nothing appeared to give me access to the "generate a String field" method, or a way to set a "for field n always use quoting" flag.

I'm about to dive into the source to see if there's some super-secret tweaks, or if there's a way to monkey-patch CSV and bend it to do my will, but wondered if anyone had some special knowledge or had run into this before.

And, yes, I know I could roll my own CSV output, but I prefer to not reinvent well-tested wheels. And, I'm also aware of FasterCSV; That's now part of Ruby 1.9.2, which I'm using, so explicitly using FasterCSV buys me nothing special. Also, I'm not using Rails and have no intention of rewriting it in Rails, so unless you have a cute way of implementing it using a small subset of Rails, don't bother. I'll downvote any recommendations to use any of those ways just because you didn't bother to read this far.

Comment: This is by far the easiest method i've found: https://superuser.com/a/318421/314320

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, there's a way to do it but it wasn't as clean as I'd hoped the CSV code could allow.

I had to subclass CSV, then override the `CSV::Row.<<=` method and add another method `forced_quote_fields=` to make it possible to define the fields I want to force-quoting on, plus pull two lambdas from other methods. At least it works for what I want:

```
require 'csv'

class MyCSV < CSV
    def <<(row)
      # make sure headers have been assigned
      if header_row? and [Array, String].include? @use_headers.class
        parse_headers  # won't read data for Array or String
        self << @headers if @write_headers
      end

      # handle CSV::Row objects and Hashes
      row = case row
        when self.class::Row then row.fields
        when Hash            then @headers.map { |header| row[header] }
        else                      row
      end

      @headers = row if header_row?
      @lineno  += 1

      @do_quote ||= lambda do |field|
        field         = String(field)
        encoded_quote = @quote_char.encode(field.encoding)
        encoded_quote                                +
        field.gsub(encoded_quote, encoded_quote * 2) +
        encoded_quote
      end

      @quotable_chars      ||= encode_str("\r\n", @col_sep, @quote_char)
      @forced_quote_fields ||= []

      @my_quote_lambda ||= lambda do |field, index|
        if field.nil?  # represent +nil+ fields as empty unquoted fields
          ""
        else
          field = String(field)  # Stringify fields
          # represent empty fields as empty quoted fields
          if (
            field.empty?                          or
            field.count(@quotable_chars).nonzero? or
            @forced_quote_fields.include?(index)
          )
            @do_quote.call(field)
          else
            field  # unquoted field
          end
        end
      end

      output = row.map.with_index(&@my_quote_lambda).join(@col_sep) + @row_sep  # quote and separate
      if (
        @io.is_a?(StringIO)             and
        output.encoding != raw_encoding and
        (compatible_encoding = Encoding.compatible?(@io.string, output))
      )
        @io = StringIO.new(@io.string.force_encoding(compatible_encoding))
        @io.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)
      end
      @io << output

      self  # for chaining
    end
    alias_method :add_row, :<<
    alias_method :puts,    :<<

    def forced_quote_fields=(indexes=[])
      @forced_quote_fields = indexes
    end
end
```

That's the code. Calling it:

```
data = [ 
  %w[1 2 3], 
  [ 2, 'two too',  3 ], 
  [ 3, 'two, too', 3 ] 
]

quote_fields = [1]

puts "Ruby version:   #{ RUBY_VERSION }"
puts "Quoting fields: #{ quote_fields.join(', ') }", "\n"

csv = MyCSV.generate do |_csv|
  _csv.forced_quote_fields = quote_fields
  data.each do |d| 
    _csv << d
  end
end

puts csv
```

results in:

```
# >> Ruby version:   1.9.2
# >> Quoting fields: 1
# >> 
# >> 1,"2",3
# >> 2,"two too",3
# >> 3,"two, too",3
```

Comment: As of Ruby 2.1.0, CSV 2.4.8, this code is now in the `init_separators` method, but is fairly similar. By monkey-patching that method, that probably ensures that other methods like `generate_line` will also use the right quoting.

Comment: As of Ruby 3, CSV has fixed the bug with `write_converters` option so I this can be run without any error `CSV.generate_line(["a", 12, nil], write_nil_value: "NaN", write_converters: ->(value) {"=#{value}"})` might help in some scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

This post is old, but I can't believe no one thought of this.

Why not do:

```
csv = CSV.generate :quote_char => "\0" do |csv|
```

where \0 is a null character, then just add quotes to each field where they are needed:

```
csv << [product.upc, "\"" + product.name + "\"" # ...
```

Then at the end you can do a

```
csv.gsub!(/\0/, '')
```

Comment: Besides the fact that the other answer already suggested this sort of solution, but post processing output of a CSV file is painful if you're dealing with huge CSV files, especially if it has to be buffered or reloaded to fix up the hack. CSV is an ugly format to begin with. It's better to fix the root-cause, even if it means touching, or overriding some code because then the process works correctly.

Comment: However, if you come here from Google, years after the fact, and not feeling like fighting with the stodgy `CSV` class (why TF couldn't they just test if the string length was `<= 1`, and not `== 1`?), and are in ownership of code that unfortunately already mutates every field, this is a hack that Just Works.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt if this will help the customer feeling warm and fuzzy after all this time, but this seems to work:

```
require 'csv'
#prepare a lambda which converts field with index 2 
quote_col2 = lambda do |field, fieldinfo|
  # fieldinfo has a line- ,header- and index-method
  if fieldinfo.index == 2 && !field.start_with?('"') then 
    '"' + field + '"'
  else
    field
  end
end

# specify above lambda as one of the converters
csv =  CSV.read("test1.csv", :converters => [quote_col2])
p csv 
# => [["aaa", "bbb", "\"ccc\"", "ddd"], ["fff", "ggg", "\"hhh\"", "iii"]]
File.open("test1.txt","w"){|out| csv.each{|line|out.puts line.join(",")}}
```

Comment: You can't apply a converter to the `generate` method, can you? The OP was asking about writing CSV files.

Comment: @jwadsack added a line writing the array to a file.

Comment: But wouldn't that fail for a field with a comma in it?

Answer (score 5):

`CSV` has a `force_quotes` option that will force it to quote all fields (it may not have been there when you posted this originally). I realize this isn't exactly what you were proposing, but it's less monkey patching.

```
2.1.0 :008 > puts CSV.generate_line [1,'1.1.1.1','Firstname Lastname','more','fields']
1,1.1.1.1,Firstname Lastname,more,fields
2.1.0 :009 > puts CSV.generate_line [1,'1.1.1.1','Firstname Lastname','more','fields'], force_quotes: true
"1","1.1.1.1","Firstname Lastname","more","fields"
```

The drawback is that the first integer value ends up listed as a string, which changes things when you import into Excel.

Comment: "...the first integer value ends up listed as a string...", which as you said, changes the value to a string. Also, I needed a specific field *always* be wrapped in quotes, not every field.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time, but since the [CSV library](https://github.com/ruby/csv) has been patched, this might help someone if they're now facing this issue:

```rb
require 'csv'

# puts CSV::VERSION # this should be 3.1.9+

headers = ['id', 'ip', 'name', 'foo', 'bar']
data = [
[1, '1.1.1.1','Firstname Lastname','more','fields'],
[2, '2.2.2.2','Firstname Lastname, Jr.','more','fields']
]

quoter = Proc.new do |field, field_meta|
 # the index starts at zero, that's why the third field would be 2:
 field = '"' + field + '"' if field_meta.index == 2 && fields_meta.index > 1
 field = '"' + field + '"' if field.is_a?(String) && field.include?(',')
 # ^ CSV format needs to escape fields containing comma(s): ,
 field
end

file = CSV.generate(headers: true, quote_char: '', write_converters: quoter) do |csv|
    csv << headers
    data.each { |row| csv << row }
end

puts file
```

the output would be:

```
id,ip,name,foo,bar
1,1.1.1.1,"Firstname Lastname",more,fields
2,2.2.2.2,"Firstname Lastname, Jr.",more,fields
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's any way to do this with the existing CSV implementation short of monkey-patching/rewriting it.

However, assuming you have full control over the source data, you could do this:

1. Append a custom string **including a comma** (i.e. one that would never be naturally found in the data) to the end of the field in question for each row; maybe something like "**FORCE_COMMAS,**".
2. Generate the CSV output.
3. Now that you have CSV output with quotes on every row for your field, remove the custom string: `csv.gsub!(/FORCE_COMMAS,/, "")`
4. Customer feels warm and fuzzy.

Comment: Once the output CSV is obtained, the `by_col!` method may help too!

Comment: It's not very elegant and isn't following the Ruby way. I guess I'll dive into the source once more.

Answer (score 0):

> CSV has changed a bit in Ruby 2.1 as mentioned by @jwadsack, however here's an working version of @the-tin-man's MyCSV. Bit modified, you set the forced_quote_fields via options.

```
MyCSV.generate(forced_quote_fields: [1]) do |_csv|...
```

The modified code

```
require 'csv'

class MyCSV < CSV

  def <<(row)
    # make sure headers have been assigned
    if header_row? and [Array, String].include? @use_headers.class
      parse_headers  # won't read data for Array or String
      self << @headers if @write_headers
    end

    # handle CSV::Row objects and Hashes
    row = case row
          when self.class::Row then row.fields
          when Hash            then @headers.map { |header| row[header] }
          else                      row
          end

    @headers =  row if header_row?
    @lineno  += 1

    output = row.map.with_index(&@quote).join(@col_sep) + @row_sep  # quote and separate
    if @io.is_a?(StringIO)             and
       output.encoding != (encoding = raw_encoding)
      if @force_encoding
        output = output.encode(encoding)
      elsif (compatible_encoding = Encoding.compatible?(@io.string, output))
        @io.set_encoding(compatible_encoding)
        @io.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)
      end
    end
    @io << output

    self  # for chaining
  end

  def init_separators(options)
    # store the selected separators
    @col_sep    = options.delete(:col_sep).to_s.encode(@encoding)
    @row_sep    = options.delete(:row_sep)  # encode after resolving :auto
    @quote_char = options.delete(:quote_char).to_s.encode(@encoding)
    @forced_quote_fields = options.delete(:forced_quote_fields) || []

    if @quote_char.length != 1
      raise ArgumentError, ":quote_char has to be a single character String"
    end

    #
    # automatically discover row separator when requested
    # (not fully encoding safe)
    #
    if @row_sep == :auto
      if [ARGF, STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR].include?(@io) or
         (defined?(Zlib) and @io.class == Zlib::GzipWriter)
        @row_sep = $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
      else
        begin
          #
          # remember where we were (pos() will raise an exception if @io is pipe
          # or not opened for reading)
          #
          saved_pos = @io.pos
          while @row_sep == :auto
            #
            # if we run out of data, it's probably a single line
            # (ensure will set default value)
            #
            break unless sample = @io.gets(nil, 1024)
            # extend sample if we're unsure of the line ending
            if sample.end_with? encode_str("\r")
              sample << (@io.gets(nil, 1) || "")
            end

            # try to find a standard separator
            if sample =~ encode_re("\r\n?|\n")
              @row_sep = $&
              break
            end
          end

          # tricky seek() clone to work around GzipReader's lack of seek()
          @io.rewind
          # reset back to the remembered position
          while saved_pos > 1024  # avoid loading a lot of data into memory
            @io.read(1024)
            saved_pos -= 1024
          end
          @io.read(saved_pos) if saved_pos.nonzero?
        rescue IOError         # not opened for reading
          # do nothing:  ensure will set default
        rescue NoMethodError   # Zlib::GzipWriter doesn't have some IO methods
          # do nothing:  ensure will set default
        rescue SystemCallError # pipe
          # do nothing:  ensure will set default
        ensure
          #
          # set default if we failed to detect
          # (stream not opened for reading, a pipe, or a single line of data)
          #
          @row_sep = $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR if @row_sep == :auto
        end
      end
    end
    @row_sep = @row_sep.to_s.encode(@encoding)

    # establish quoting rules
    @force_quotes   = options.delete(:force_quotes)
    do_quote        = lambda do |field|
      field         = String(field)
      encoded_quote = @quote_char.encode(field.encoding)
      encoded_quote                                +
      field.gsub(encoded_quote, encoded_quote * 2) +
      encoded_quote
    end
    quotable_chars = encode_str("\r\n", @col_sep, @quote_char)

    @quote         = if @force_quotes
      do_quote
    else
      lambda do |field, index|
        if field.nil?  # represent +nil+ fields as empty unquoted fields
          ""
        else
          field = String(field)  # Stringify fields
          # represent empty fields as empty quoted fields
          if field.empty? or
             field.count(quotable_chars).nonzero? or
             @forced_quote_fields.include?(index)
            do_quote.call(field)
          else
            field  # unquoted field
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```