# Format csv in ruby so that string columns have double-quotes, but numerical columns don't

Tags: ruby, csv, quotes

I am trying to output a CSV file in ruby, that looks like this:

```
"numeric_column","string_column"
1,"string1"
2,"long string"
```

I could only find a way to have no quotes at all or quotes also on the numeric column.

My code looks like this now:

```
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb", force_quotes: true, headers: ['id', 'name'], write_headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << [id, name]
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I force one field in Ruby's CSV output to be wrapped with double-quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854900/how-do-i-force-one-field-in-rubys-csv-output-to-be-wrapped-with-double-quotes)

Comment: Can you describe this a bit more - what's the question here?

Comment: @locoboy I was hoping that there's an easy, nice solution like being able to describe the column types similar to how we pass the headers in CSV.open, something like: CSV.open("file.csv", "wb", columns: {'id' => :no_quote, 'name' => :quote}) Unfortunatelly it seems that my question was really a duplicate and there's no nice solution